# How to combine Access tables based on calculated fields for an Export to Excel?

Tags: ms-access, datatables

In Access I have two tables:

Table 1 called Base:

| ID | Prod | Area | Ref | Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 124 | A | 124A | R |
| 2 | 125 | B | 125B | G |
| 3 | 126 | C | 126C | B |
| 4 | 127 | D | 127D | G |

Table 2 called Full:

| ID | Item | Area | Ref | Pos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12403 | A | 124A | 3 |
| 2 | 12502 | B | 125B | 2 |
| 3 | 12605 | C | 126C | 5 |
| 4 | 12702 | D | 127D | 2 |

In both tables, `Ref` column is a calculated field based on the two previous columns. In the first table, the `Prod` and `Area` columns are added to give the `Ref` column. In the second table, it takes the 3 first characters of the `Item` column, and the `Area` column is added to give the `Ref` column for each line.

The fact is both tables have more columns.

I would like to export a table to Excel, which, based on the calculated field `Ref` of the Full table, contains all the columns of the Full table and adds the information present in the Base table related to `Ref`. If it is not clear, see below the table I would like to get in Excel:

| Item | Area | Ref | Pos | Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12403 | A | 124A | 3 | R |
| 12502 | B | 125B | 2 | G |
| 12605 | C | 126C | 5 | B |
| 12702 | D | 127D | 2 | G |

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are both ID fields autonumber type? Is the Ref value unique in each table? Did you try joining on the calculated fields? Works for me.

Comment: ID fields are auto number type and Ref value is unique in each table. I did not try joining on the calculated fields as I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Okay, did you try the JOIN?

Comment: No, I will try and let you know

Comment: You do it same as you would JOIN on any fields. Use Access query designer to help get correct syntax.

Comment: I just tried the Inner Join and it worked perfectly!